# localisation of iphone without changing iphone settings

Tags: iphone, localization

i had done localisation by changing the language of iPhone through localisableString and by different xib which works only with NSLocale method ,but the requirement of app is to localised it by changing the language in app setting view irrespective of iPhone language..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a stupid requirement, but anyway: You can change the language of your app by setting an array with the order of preferred languages for the user defaults key @"AppleLanguages", e.g.:

```
//Set language to German:
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"de"]
                                      forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Note however that this only affects strings/nibs you load *afterwards*, so you might need to reload your UI after changing the setting.

Comment: Actually, also new calls to `NSLocalizedString` will not work as expected if you change this setting. You need to *restart* the app, which is a UI nightmare.